# IDT - How to get previous month (December) from current Month

Tags: sql, date, case, getdate

This is what I have so far. 
I am trying to have filter that will always display Last Full Month.
Below query works for all months except for January.

```
DateDim_End_Date.YEAR=year(getDate())
and DateDim_End_Date.MONTHNUMBER = month(getDate())-1
```

I was trying something like

```
CASE WHEN (DateDim_End_Date.MONTHNUMBER = month(getDate())) = 1 THEN 
(DateDim_End_Date.YEAR=year(getDate())-1
and DateDim_End_Date.MONTHNUMBER = month(getDate())-1)
WHEN DateDim_End_Date.MONTHNUMBER = month(getDate())) != 1 THEN 
(DateDim_End_Date.YEAR=year(getDate())
and DateDim_End_Date.MONTHNUMBER = month(getDate())-1)
END
```

It does not have to be CASE statement to solve this, it was just my initial approach
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
DateDim_End_Date.YEAR=year(getDate())
and DateDim_End_Date.MONTHNUMBER = month(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getDate()))
```

That will solve the issue with January, since you are now first subtracting a month from a date before determining what the new month is.

It is much easier to store dates in a single date/datetime column though.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I will certainly keep that in mind!